# Alert users to new records

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi i am trying to figure out how to architecture my alert service for my users. There are scenarios where a user will need to be alerted.

1) When a user receives a new message from another user
2) When a user is meant to start a task

Alerts are saved in a cache, however i thought it would be overkill to check this cache every few minutes, especially with the number of users i have. What i want to do is only display an alert when a new record has been added. Can anyone tell me how they will go about this scenario. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a **technique** called **Comet** and its the one that you can use on your case.

**[Comet technique](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming))** creates and open connection to your server from the client, and when the server close the connection means that there is a new message for your client, your client reads the messages, and opens a new connection wait for the next message. The other way is to just open a connection and streaming the data, when their are available from the server to the client, and not close the connection at all. The only think that you need to take care is to increase the number of open connection that allowed to your site.

Check this sites for comet with asp.net

http://www.frozenmountain.com/websync/

or

http://www.aaronlerch.com/blog/2007/07/08/creating-comet-applications-with-aspnet/

Comment: Thanks for respondign i will check this out.